# How can I search an Android ListView using hidden keywords?

Tags: android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a list of rooms.

Some of the rooms in the list are `Students`' `Activity Center`, `Classroom 101`, and `Classroom 102`.

I also have an EditText which allows the user to search a room in the list.

However, I also want to add additional keywords which would not appear on the list but are searchable. For example, if the user searches for "`SAC`", the Students' Activity Center will be shown in the ListView.

Right now, the user could only search what is visible in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 override methods **setTag**(Object tag) and setTag (**int key, Object tag**) methods. Link at [View setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)). Afterwards you call getTag to get the keywords, as you put it. Sample code:

```
String itemName = (String) myButton.getTag();
```

The idea of using **tags** is not new and has been used in various different libraries and frameworks.